# Find $xz_x+yz_y$ at a point $\left(\begin{matrix} a \\ b \end{matrix}\right)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to find $xz_x+yz_y$ at a point $\left(\begin{matrix} a \\ b \end{matrix}\right)$, if $z(x,y)=\tan\left(\frac{ax}{by}   \right)+\arctan\left( \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} \right)$. I know that it will be solved by using polar coordinates $x=r\cos\phi \text{ and } y=r\sin\phi$, but I don't know why? Also it is given then that $z_r=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$. And after this it is concluded that $z \cdot z_r=xz_x+yz_y$. Why?

Then $$r \cdot z_r = \tan\left(\frac{a\cos\phi r}{b\sin\phi r}\right)+ \arctan\left(\frac{r^2 \cos(2\phi)}{r^2}\right)$$

First, I don't get where the expression is multipliesd by $r$? For $\tan$ simply $x$ and $y$ are expressed in previously stated polar coordinates . With $\arctan$ I don't understand why $x^2-y^2=r^2\cos(2\phi)$

Lastly it is concluded that the value of $xz_x+yz_y$ is $0$ for all $a \text{ and } b$. Again, I don't understand why?

Comment: Likely, polar coordinates make the calculations easier, but are not necessary.$$x z_x + y z_y = x \left(\frac{a \sec ^2\left(\frac{a x}{b y}\right)}{b y}+\frac{2 x y^2}{x^4+y^4}\right)+y \left(-\frac{a x \sec ^2\left(\frac{a x}{b y}\right)}{b y^2}-\frac{2 x^2 y}{x^4+y^4}\right) = 0$$

Comment: @Moo And why it is $0$ for all $a,b$?

Comment: What do you get if you add the two expressions, regardless of $a, b$? I have not yet substituted those in.

Comment: @Moo you get $0$

Comment: Side question: Have you seen Euler's Theorem on Homogeneous Functions? That's the easiest way to get the answer $0$ immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have that $x = r\cos\phi$ and $y = r\sin\phi$, we can calculate the partials

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = \cos\phi = \frac{r\cos\phi}{r} = \frac{x}{r}$$

and similarly for $y$. This immediately lets us conclude that

$$r\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} = x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

Now simply just plugging in the polar coordinates into $z$ we get

$$z(r,\phi) = \tan\left(\frac{ar\cos\phi}{br\sin\phi}\right) + \arctan\left(\frac{r^2\cos^2\phi-r^2\sin^2\phi}{r^2}\right) = \tan\left(\frac{a}{b}\cot\phi\right) + \arctan(\cos 2\phi)$$

$\cos 2\phi = \cos^2\phi - \sin^2\phi$ is the standard double angle trig identity.

Notice that $z$ is completely independent of $r$, so its partial with respect to $r$ vanishes everywhere.